# Connect()-ing a http socket succeeds even without internet. Why?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, network-programming, debian

I need a method to quickly check from my C program if the internet is available on the Rasberry Pi OS (debian), on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

Unfortunately, when using the following code `connect()` returns zero (meaning that the connection was successful) practically always, ***even if my router's WAN port is unplugged*** (and has been unpulgged for a while).

```
struct addrinfo hints, *res;
int sockfd;
int retv=-1;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);                                                
hints.ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;                                                  
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if (0 == getaddrinfo("www.example.com", "http", &hints, &res)){
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd >= 0){
        retv = connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
        close(sockfd);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);
}
if (retv == 0)
    //successful
else
    //unsuccessful
```

Is this completely a bad idea, or am I just missing something?

Comment: A successful connect means that a three-way-handshake is completed (`SYN` / `SYN-ACK` / `ACK`). Are you sure your packets cannot find their way, different to the one you're disabling, to `www.example.com`?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Yes. Wlan0 is associated with my local wifi but the cable that goes into the router's wan port is intentionally unplugged from the wall; router's config page confirms this fact. The raspberry's lan port is also unconnected. Pinging any web address fails. So yes, I'm quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

Something weird is going on. The question is where is it happening?

First, does this happen with a small program that does nothing other than the posted code?  Does it compile warning-free with all compiler warning enabled?

If this is part of a larger program, there's no way to rule out undefined behavior resulting from something like heap corruption from a buffer overflow.  `getaddrinfo()` likely uses `malloc()` or something similar to allocate its result, so this could happen.

If you have [`strace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) available, you can run your process under `strace` and see the actual system calls made and their results.

You could also check the actual data returned by `getaddrinfo()`.  Because per [POSIX `connect()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/connect.html):

> ... If the sa_family member of address is `AF_UNSPEC`, the socket's peer address shall be reset. Note that despite no connection being made, the term ``connected'' is used to describe a connectionless-mode socket for which a peer address has been set. ...

That's similar behavior to what you're seeing.  You can print the contents of the `res` structure before calling `connect()`:

```
if (0 == getaddrinfo("www.example.com", "http", &hints, &res)){
    printf( "res->ai_family = %d, AF_UNSPEC = %d\n",
        res->ai_family, AF_UNSPEC );
    printf( "res->ai_socktype = %d, SOCK_STREAM = %d\n",
        res->ai_socktype, SOCK_STREAM );

    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd >= 0){
        retv = connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
        close(sockfd);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);
}
```